# Cannot select UICollectionView Cell when Highlighting is set to false

Tags: swift, ios8, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I've been battling with this for a while. The core issue is that my cells in a UICollectionView are disappearing when they are highlighted. I have no need for highlighting on my app, just selecting, so i've set:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, shouldHighlightItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    return false
}
```

which means i'm not getting the highlight callbacks, or the undesired behaviour, but i'm no longer able to select items, even when setting:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, shouldHighlightItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

didSelectItemAtIndexPath is not getting called.

Am i missing a flag or something?

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: u may check this  http://stackoverflow.com/a/20380698/3400991

Answer (score 0):

It is by design so:

> This issue behaves as intended based on the following:
>   The sequence is:
>   if shouldHighlight == YES
>   didHighlight
>   shouldSelect
>   didSelect
>   Highlighting is pre-condition to selection.
>
> By avedesk at Oct. 11, 2016, 9:37 p.m. (reply...)

[Source](http://www.openradar.me/28334424)