# collectionviewcell didSelectItemAtIndexPath/didDeselectItemAtIndexPath not responding for specific cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, selector, uicollectionviewcell

I am trying to preselect some of the cell according to condition, which sets those cells selected and also change its background color while drawing those cells. Now the method

**`didSelectItemAtIndexPath / didDeselectItemAtIndexPath`**

is not getting called only for those `preselected` cells and hence I am not able to toggle selection and `background color`. The `select/deselect delegate methods` are being called for other cells

```
    -(UICollectionViewCell*) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
        NSLog(@"cellForItemAtIndexPath: %@", indexPath);
        CollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"collectionViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

        if(indexPath.row != 0 && indexPath.row != 8 && indexPath.section != 0 && indexPath.section != 25){
            NSMutableDictionary *blockedHours = [blockedDaysArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row-1];
            NSString *blockedVal = [blockedHours valueForKey:@(indexPath.section-1).stringValue];
            [cell setBlockedVal:(NSString*)blockedVal];
        }
        [cell addDayTimeLable:indexPath];
        return cell;
    }

    -(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
        NSLog(@"didSelectItemAtIndexPath: %@ ", indexPath);
        NSMutableDictionary *blockedHours = [blockedDaysArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row-1];
        [blockedHours setValue:@"1" forKey:@(indexPath.section-1).stringValue];
        CollectionViewCell *cell = (CollectionViewCell*)[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell.selected = YES;
    }

    -(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didDeselectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
        NSLog(@"didDeselectItemAtIndexPath %@", indexPath);
        NSMutableDictionary *blockedHours = [blockedDaysArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row-1];
        [blockedHours setValue:@"0" forKey:@(indexPath.section-1).stringValue];
        CollectionViewCell *cell = (CollectionViewCell*)[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell.selected = NO;
    }
```

In CollectionViewCell.m:

Self.selected calls the setter method and hence chagnes the background color

```
    -(void)setBlockedVal:(NSString*)blockedVal{
        if([blockedVal isEqualToString:@"1"]){
            self.selected = YES;
        }
    }


    -(void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected{
        NSLog(@"set selected: %d", selected);
        [super setSelected:selected];
        if(selected)
            self.backgroundColor = [SFIColors lightGreenColor];
        else
            self.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    }
```

Note:

> (1) didHighlightItemAtIndexPath/didUnHighlightItemAtIndexPath are
>   getting called for preselected cells.
>
> (2)I Just found out that setting selected via didselect/didunselect is
>   redundant and I just removed from my code.Noticed that setSeleted is
>   auto called on clicking the other cells. Still this setSelected is not
>   being for preselected cells

Any Inputs to fix this or another way that I can do my task would be of great help.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in this link: [UICollectionView - didDeselectItemAtIndexPath not called if cell is selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20380512/uicollectionview-diddeselectitematindexpath-not-called-if-cell-is-selected)

I actually searched a lot actually, but only now I found this link.

I had let my collection view know about my selection and that did the trick:

```
[collectionView selectItemAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionNone];
```