# didSelectItemAt and didDeselectItemAt are not working as expected in swift 3.0

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift3, uicollectionviewcell

I am using  didSelectItemAt and didDeselectItemAt  for multiple selection of collectionViewCell. I want to select the cell and make the border blue color if it is selected and also unselect the 'selected' cell and make the border default. But my problem is that didDeselectItemAt is getting called alternately. when once i tap on any cell then didSelectItemAt is called and if i tap on any other cell then didDeselectItemAt is called. This should not happen i guess. didDeselectItemAt  should be called only if i am tapping on already selected cell. Please correct me if i am going wrong. I have refered this [UICollectionView - didDeselectItemAtIndexPath not called if cell is selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20380512/uicollectionview-diddeselectitematindexpath-not-called-if-cell-is-selected])[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20380512/uicollectionview-diddeselectitematindexpath-not-called-if-cell-is-selected) but dint work for me :(

```
public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
   let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as!  MomentDetailCell
   let moment = self.arrOfMoments[indexPath.row] as! MomentModel
   cell.toggleSelection(moment: moment)
   self.arrOfDeletingImgs.append(moment) 
}

public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
   let cell : MomentDetailCell = self.collectionViewImages.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! MomentDetailCell
   let moment = self.arrOfMoments[indexPath.row] as! MomentModel
   cell.toggleSelection(moment: moment)
   self.arrOfDeletingImgs.remove(at: (find(objecToFind: moment))!)
}
```

// Also this is the code i am using in the class. I have also made allowsMultipleSelection true in viewdidload

```
 extension MomentDetailViewController : UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout
{
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize
    {
      return CGSize(width: 75, height: 75)
    }
}
```

// This is my customCell code

```
func toggleSelection( moment : MomentModel)
{
    if (isSelected)
    {
        moment.isSelected = true
        self.layer.borderWidth = 3
        self.layer.borderColor = Constant.APP_BLUE_COLOR.cgColor

    }
    else
    {
        moment.isSelected = false
        self.layer.borderWidth = 1
        self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess didselect method is called when you tap on second cell so first gets deselected.You are tapping on first again and keeping it selected ,and have you checked it goes to else ? You need to save selected index state somewhere.

Answer (score 4):

Try this :

**This solution for multiple selection**

1- make deSelect as below

```
 public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)
    {
       let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as!  MomentDetailCell
       let moment = self.arrOfMoments[indexPath.row] as! MomentModel
       cell.toggleSelection(moment: moment)
       self.arrOfDeletingImgs.append(moment) 
    }
```

2 - Comment/Remove Deselect method

3 change in this method

```
func toggleSelection( moment : MomentModel)
{
   moment.isSelected = !moment.isSelected
   self.layer.borderWidth =  moment.isSelected ? 3 : 1
   self.layer.borderColor =  moment.isSelected ?  Constant.APP_BLUE_COLOR.cgColor :  UIColor.red.cgColor

}
```

Comment: There is no valid change in your answer. You have just optimized the code by using ternary operator instead of if else.

Comment: i have mentioned for remove your didDeselectItemAt method also .

Comment: ok Thanks. Anyway it wouldnt have worked as i was setting selction false for every cell in cellforItem by refering other answers on  [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20380512/uicollectionview-diddeselectitematindexpath-not-called-if-cell-is-selected)  i sadly mixed various answers.

Answer (score 4):

**After long time i troubleshooted the problem and this is what worked for me...**

*I was doing following thing in cellForItemAtIndexPath: which is **WRONG***

**cell.isSelected = false

collectionView.selectItem(at: indexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: .left)**

I was doing this as didDeselect was getting called alternately without considering the selection of cell. I just uncommeted this code and it worked for me. Now didSelect is calling on first click and if i click on same cell  again then only didDeselect is called as per expected flow.

**Also make sure allowsMultipleSelection is true and also allowsSelection is true**

Answer (score 2):

I guess didselect method is called when you tap on second cell. Might be you forgot:

```
_collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = YES
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case i had a separate delegate class, and if i set `collectionView.delegate = MyDelegate()`, it didnt work, if i stored a `var myDelegate = MyDelegate()`in my viewcontroller and then set `collectionView.delegate = myDelegate` it somehow worked.